# Why does this jQuery selector return only 1 element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

So, I have this next variable that contains my checked checkboxes:

```
var checked = $('input[name="article[]"]:checked');
```

But how can I know if there is 1 checked, 2 or even none? Because `console.log(checked.length)` always returns 1.

Comment: And if you use this selector instead? `'input[name="article\\[\\]"]:checked'`

Comment: @MattBall it's inside a quoted string, I don't believe their parser is that bad. http://jsfiddle.net/7R4U4/

Comment: I'd test your selector. If it really is selecting all of the checked boxes `.length` should be working.

Comment: But the Html is like that: `<input type="checkbox" name="article[]" val="1" /><input type="checkbox" name="article[]" val="2" checked />`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's a stupid mistake but for everybody to know, the problem was that I was doing this:

```
if(checked.length = 1) {
```

instead of this

```
if(checked.length == 1) {
```

btw, I don't know why the "hate" on the other answers (for those who down voted), the answers given... work (I've tested 2 of them)

Comment: I used to do that ALL the time!

Comment: Because the answers didn't solve any problems, even if you are using their code, `if( checked.length = 1 )` would not work. Your selector was correct from the beginning so the answers modifying it are not helpful in my opinion.

Comment: oh no ;) it happens to the best of us though!

Comment: If that happens all the time with you,

Do this,
`if(1 == checked.length)` , if you miss, there will be an error :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('input[name=article\\[\\]]:checked').length
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dyrD5/

Comment: @Wesley Murch But it became necessary after jquery 1.6. See http://jsfiddle.net/dyrD5/

Comment: @SilverLight but it isn't http://jsfiddle.net/7R4U4/ The parser would be completely crap if this was required. His original attr value was quoted, that means you can put any character there without having to escape except \\ or " in the context of the selector language

Answer (score -1):

Who downclicked codeparadoxes answer? Right selector, just needs length

```
<input type="checkbox" name="article" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="article" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="article" value="3" />
<button>go</button>
```

​
js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        alert($('input[name^="article"]:checked').length)
    })
});​
```

Working here http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/GLjTg/

Comment: Partial attribute selectors can match too many elements and cause mistakes/errors. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/GLjTg/1/ (BTW He deleted his answer)

Comment: good shout on the partial selectors... I just got the fiddle up quickly cos I wanted to show that his answer did 'work' ;)